# Get the value of an input scope with angular ng-switch

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-scope

***What it should do***

Each button is linked to a div block (ex: button01 links to block01). Each div block has 3 inputs. The last input gets the value of the a math function between the two inputs above it. The div blocks must "appear" not show/hide.

***What it does***

The part where the three buttons open the three div blocks works. The problem is that when I try to type something inside the two inputs the last input gets nothing.

***What I've tried***

1) ng-switch and ng-switch-when

2) place the divs inside each `(script type="text/ng-template" id="aaa")`
and then;

```
var forms = ["aaa", "bbb", "ccc", "ddd"];

credit_block.displayedForms = [];

credit_block.addForm = function(formIndex) {
    credit_block.displayedForms = [];
    credit_block.displayedForms.push(forms[formIndex]);     
}
```

3) (this one worked but it's not what I want) ng-show

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>


<div class="row">
   <div class="col-sm-12">
     Pick a topic:
     <label><span>Button01</span><input style="display:none" type="radio" ng-model="myVar" value="block01"></label>
     <label><span>Button02</span><input style="display:none" type="radio" ng-model="myVar" value="block02"></label>
     <label><span>Button03</span><input style="display:none" type="radio" ng-model="myVar" value="block03"></label>
   </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="row" ng-switch="myVar">
   <div class="col-sm-12" ng-switch-when="block01">
    <h3>Cumpar locuinta</h3>
    <div class="row">
     <div class="col-sm-10 col-xs-8 number-box">
      <label>Sum:</label>
      <input class="button-option" type="number" ng-model="sum">
     </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
     <div class="col-sm-10 col-xs-8 number-box">
      <label>Advancement:</label>
      <input class="button-option" type="number" ng-model="adv">
     </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
     <div class="col-sm-10 col-xs-8 number-box">
      <label>Value:</label>
      <input class="button-option" type="number" value="{{ result() }}">
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  
  </div>
 </div>

<script>
 var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
 myApp.controller('myController', function($scope) {
  $scope.sum = 5;
  $scope.adv = 4;
        $scope.result = function() {            
                return $scope.sum - $scope.adv;
        };
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You've got a classic scope-related variable shadowing problem.

`ng-switch` creates a new scope, so your `ng-model` bindings to `sum` and `adv` don't correspond to the ones you've set up in `myController`.

A usual way to work around this newly created scope is to put `ng-model` properties for binding behind an object and reference them through it.

For example, in your HTML:

```
<input class="button-option" type="number" ng-model="data.sum">
```

Then in your controller:

```
$scope.data = { sum: ... };
```

[Here's a demonstration of your snippet with some amendments to make it work.](http://plnkr.co/edit/3PFBYP?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks mister. I'm new to angular.